# Issue with Skitter Slideshow

Tags: jquery

As you can see, I tried the code on skitter's install site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_skitter_large").skitter();
    });
</script>

<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#cut"><img src="images/001.jpg" class="cut" /></a>
            <div class="label_text"><p>cut</p></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#swapBlocks"><img src="images/002.jpg" class="swapBlocks" /></a>
            <div class="label_text"><p>swapBlocks</p></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#swapBarsBack"><img src="images/003.jpg" class="swapBarsBack" /></a>
            <div class="label_text"><p>swapBarsBack</p></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

check out the jsfiddle for the page, and you'll see the problem here. The images are loading under the slider, I've tried changing the jquery files.

**JSFIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/RGj7n/

This slideshow is not working right

Comment: Maybe you need to change the order of your CSS files included in the page.

Comment: @EmCo I've tried, I copied the order directly on the site

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/Images/featured.jpg" class="block" /></a>
        <div class="label_text">
            <p>Label</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/Images/featured2.jpg" class="cube" /></a>
        <div class="label_text">
            <p>Label</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/Images/featured3.jpg" class="default" /></a>
        <div class="label_text">
            <p>Label</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I changed the code to the above, then I edited the size of the image in the skitter style sheets.

Works perfectly now.